# Usage of Windows+Number combination on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

`Windows 7` has built-in keyboard shortcuts of <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> .. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> which allow to easily switch to the application whose Index in the `Taskbar` is the one used in the combination.
This is very nice for the 1st and 2nd application, and even the 3rd - but what happens when I want to open the Application with Index #7? I actually need to count and see if it is #7 which makes the shortcut less friendly.

I thought of editing the Icon of each application pinned to the `Taskbar` and add a number to it with its index, but that seems annoying to do and does not support none-pinned applications.

Does `Windows 7` support some kind of "highlighting" of the application's index when I hold the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key like it does for menus when I hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Comment: And don’t forget, if you drag the icons around, you can rearrange them, but their labels won’t get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no easy way of highlighting/adding a number to the taskbar. An alternative way of doing it, if you always have a lot of application open, is to put the number on the wallpaper so that it approximately shows the numbering above each application when the taskbar is all filled with icons.